# jQuery how to replace all contents of an element into another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have 3 elements like below with different html contents:

```
<div id='result1'> <p>One</p> </div>
<div id='result2'> <p>Two</p> </div>
<div id='result3'> <p>Three</p> </div>
```

How can I copy just contents within the div element to the next one so that the final result looks like this?

```
<div id='result1'> <p>New content</p> </div>
<div id='result2'> <p>One</p> </div>
<div id='result3'> <p>Two</p> </div>
```

There will be new content for replacement and the last content can be discarded.
To clarify, I'll have something like:

```
<div id='new'> <p>New content</p> </div>
```

where I want to grab `'<p>New content</p>'` as new content to use.

What do you think?

Comment: It's easy enough to *do*, but why would you *want* to?

Answer (score 2):

To push the content down, reverse the collection and set the HTML to the HTML of the previous one.

```
var elems = $($('[id^=result]').get().reverse());

elems.html(function(i) {
    return elems.eq(i+1).html();
}).last().html('New Content');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U78xW/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on the element you want to change the content. For accessing particular element you can use [ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) with [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T5ELs/)**

```
$('#result1 > p').html('New content');
```

**Edit** to move contents to next elements you can iterate through all elements and start assigning the context of second last to last, third last to second last and so on

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T5ELs/1/)**

```
elements = $('[id^=result] > p');
len = elements.length;
elements.each(function(idx, el){
   if(idx == elements.length-1) return; 
   $('#result'+ (len-idx) + ' p').html($('#result' + (len-idx-1) + ' p').html());   
});

$('#result1 > p').html('New content');
```

Comment: `$('#result1 p').html('New content');`

Comment: why to search parent and again search for child, instead of that we can give id directly to child and can replace content of it right ??

Comment: Well id is not given to child in the OP and its not always possible or desirable to give id to element we want. If it is possible then it is always best to get element by id

Comment: Question is.. how do I grab the all new content of the element? Eg, if  have have a new element with <div id='new'> <p>New content</p> </div>, how would I grab all the content, ie '<p>New content</p>' so that I could use it here $('#result1 > p').html(???);

Comment: $('#new').html() will give you  <p>New content</p>

Answer (score 0):

try JS [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/qVGxR/)

I am suggesting to add a Parent Grid and use jquery first() and last(), These controls will function like a queue.

```
$('#Pdiv').children().last().remove();
$('#Pdiv').first().prepend("<div id='new'> <p>I am New One</p></div>");

alert($('#Pdiv').children().first().html());
```